# How to change a Maya scene file's selected viewport renderer from the file itself (text edit)?

Tags: maya

So I have been running Viewport 2.0 in my 2012 version of Maya for a couple weeks with no problem. Day before yesterday it started crashing on load with a random MSVC dll pointer error. It's common, but a work around doesn't exist. Anyone know how to modify my .ma scene file contents so that none of my viewports are running Viewport 2.0?

I can import my stuff to another scene, but it's not fun.

Comment: Note that it's perfectly acceptable to accept your own answers on the site if they fully answer your question. Makes things more tidy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. Just do a Find/Replace searching for *ogsRenderer* and replace it with *base_OpenGL_Renderer*.